# How do I generate a .condor file

Tags: java, batch-file, condor

I have created a batch file which executes a .jar perfectly fine from the command prompt. I am trying to submit this to condor, but need to first compile a .condor.

I am unsure how to do this, do I need to be in a specific directory or already within the condor environment?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://wiki.umiacs.umd.edu/umiacs/index.php/CondorJava) helps?

Comment: haha yup, thanks! realised it was just a text file saved as condor. I'm a bit new to programming so reading the manual I didn't spot this